# R2 cross validation metric vs linear regression R2

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, scikit-learn, polynomial, scipy

I've been using sklearn for a project I'm working on. I'm following [this](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html) example for analyzing my data. I believe I have an overfitting problem, but before I try to address it I want to make sure I'm using/understanding sklearn correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict,cross_val_score,train_test_split

#... prepare data ...
fold = 10

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=polyDegree)
lr = LinearRegression(normalize=True)

pipeline = Pipeline([("polynomial",poly),
                     ("lr",lr)])

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline,data,target,
                         scoring="r2", cv=fold)

print("Score: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

predicted = cross_val_predict(pipeline,data,target,cv=fold)

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(target,predicted)

info = "N: %2i Slope: %6.2f Intercept: %6.2f R2: %6.2f P_value: %6.2e"%\
  (len(target),slope,intercept,r_value*r_value,p_value)
print info
```

Which tells me:

```
Score: -3.21 (+/- 12.21)
N: 31 Slope:   1.07 Intercept:   0.19 R2:   0.47 P_value: 2.27e-05
```

I would have guessed that the R2 scores would be similar, but "-3.21" seems very different than "0.47", even if I'm overfitting. Is my `linregress` adding new degrees of freedom that are not being captured by my `LinearRegression`? Is there some metric I can use with `cross_val_score` that will get me the `linregress` score?

Comment: Some of the concepts you are using are not very general, and require a knowledge of Python code alone rather than math/stats. Those should be generalized so that the average reader can understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Carl, thanks... I'm headed out now, so I'll update this later. I think sklearn is giving me "coefficient of determination" and linregress is giving me "coefficient of correlation", and both quantities are labeled "R2"... so maybe my code is ok, I just need to figure out how to interpret "coefficient of determination".